# syntonly: warning (font): lua-loaded font '16' with name 'dummy' has no characters

Tags: fonts, luatex, warnings, characters, syntax-checker

I get this warning when compiling a document which uses `syntonly` with LuaLaTeX.
Does every font have an ID and 16 links to the 16th font which was loaded?
Where is the dummy font and why do I get this warning?

Is it a false alert, because the dummy is always empty?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\syntaxonly
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a compilable example that produces this warning.

Comment: The standard LaTeX package `syntonly` uses `dummy.tfm`, which is a font with enough font parameters to qualify as a math font, as a replacement for every called font; it indeed has no characters. In the olden days using `syntonly` could save a lot of time when looking for errors, because it essentially typeset nothing, but syntax checking was done.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much. I think this is exactly the source of the problem.

Comment: @Marijn I was able to reduce the book to an MWE now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the olden days, typesetting a big book could literally take *hours*. Most of the time was and is spent in breaking paragraphs into lines, breaking paragraphs into pages and in I/O operations. The overhead is small with modern machines, in the 80's it used to be huge.

Appendix D of the TeXbook has a section about “doing only syntax check” without typesetting and suggests using a dummy font that has no characters, but enough font parameters to be used as a math symbol font (that is, 22) and change the font associations to this dummy font for all fonts.

When Michael Spivak wrote AMS-TeX, he took the advice and indeed AMS-TeX came with `dummy.tfm`.

If you look into `amstex.tex`, you will see that each font is loaded with a different syntax than plain TeX, namely

```latex
\font@\tenmsa=msam10
```

The definition is

```latex
\def\font@#1=#2 {\rightappend@#1\to\fontlist@\font#1=#2 }
```

This means that AMS-TeX maintains a list of the defined font so it's possible to issue the command `\syntax` that performs several operations, among which traversing the `\fontlist@` list and doing `\font\tenmsa=dummy` (the same for each defined font); besides it does `\tracinglostchars=0`, so not to litter the log file with lots of “Missing character” warnings.

Thus the document would be compiled and no text would be set (well, almost no text), but macros would be expanded and errors could be caught.

LaTeX2e took advantage of this scheme and provided the `syntonly` package that essentially mimics what AMS-TeX's `\syntax` command did, but using LaTeX's font selection scheme. You also need `\syntaxonly` if you want just syntax check to be performed.

Thus if you load the `syntonly` package, you will get the warning by LuaTeX that the `dummy` font has no characters, because indeed it has none.

Here's the human readable version of `dummy.tfm`, which is now part of the `amsfonts` suite:

```
(FAMILY UNSPECIFIED)
(FACE F MRR)
(CODINGSCHEME NULL FONT FOR SYNTAX CHECKING)
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 1234567)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.0)
   (STRETCH R 0.0)
   (SHRINK R 0.0)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.0)
   (QUAD R 0.0)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 8 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 9 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 10 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 11 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 12 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 13 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 14 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 15 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 16 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 17 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 18 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 19 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 20 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 21 R 0.0)
   (PARAMETER D 22 R 0.0)
   )
```